# What's it called when you have multiple network adapters and use them with different software

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet

I am looking to setup a new in-home server using an old laptop.

It will have an external USB drive, which will be a NAS. I will also have a Plex server and the usual LAMP.

Due to the slow 100Mbps ethernet adapter, I want to add a Gigabit "Ethernet to USB adapter". I want to setup the Plex server to use the built in ethernet port, and the NAS and Webserver to use the Gigabit ethernet to usb adapter. As I should be able to get a few more MBs file transfer out of the USB port.

I can't see why this wouldn't be possible.  What do you call it when you use more than one ethernet adapter and use different ones from different software?

Comment: I've edited your question as well i can to make it hopefully more understandable, particularly that you don't want a solution, you just want to know what it's called when you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to bind a service to a specific network interface, ie to a specific ip adress.
It is *binding* a service to a listening ip address or interface.
There is probably no specific HowTo about doing this, but it is just a part of the configuration process for each of the services you plan to deploy.

Comment: Thank you, I am looking for 'binding' or so I know now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple network adapters, your computer will have an IP address on each one, that is unique to that network, so your computer will typically have a different IP address on each adapter.

In a piece of software that listens to incoming network connections you can usually tell it which adapter to listen to (to *bind to*) usually by telling it which IP address to listen on.  By default most software listens on all incoming interfaces, which means it will listen on all adapters at once - and this should not usually lead to conflicts because your computer can handle a request coming in on any interface and will ensure that replies go out on the same interface.

If you really do want to limit a piece of software so it *only* listens to incoming requests from a particular interface then you'll need to bind it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the term you are looking for is "hybrid network". Various connection methods for a given network.
See these sources:
[Definition of: hybrid network](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/44545/hybrid-network)
[What Are Hybrid Networks?](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/what-are-hybrid-networks)

Comment: Thanks, cool read. I think I was looking for 'binding' though.. or so I think. Thanks though.